# CSS: invisible background on margin

Tags: css

this is something rather simple I think, so I'll just paste the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        .c1 {
            background: yellow;
            width: 800px;
        }

        .c2 {
            background: blue;
            margin: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">  
        1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, why there isn't a yellow strip at the top or bottom of the page? I think it should be in controlled space of c1 but the background color is just invisible.

Comment: give float:left to C1 and then check it. There will be a yellow strip then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of collapsing margins. Add `overflow:auto` to your c1 rules:

```
 .c1 {
     background: yellow;
     width: 800px;
     overflow:auto;
 }
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Cuprs/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is margin collapse issue. Add padding to c1 for desired effect in this Instance. I have answered more complex issues surrounding margin collapse but this doesn't require such measures.